# How do I override Rails's default migration generator to add a small piece of functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, rails-generators

I'd like to include one line of code by default in all migrations I create. (Actually, just a comment to disable a certain Rubocop check).

Can I use inheritance to achieve this without re-implementing the functionality of the default `rails g migration`?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

Comment: Can you include the one line of code in your question?

Comment: @dgolman: Done -- it's just a comment, actually.